# Lotus Notes CSV Export-Change string qualifier

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a way to export lotus notes view into csv file with string qualifier as anything except double quotes like a tilde(~)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and Googling I was not able to anything to prove me wrong), using File->Export, no.  There are other options.  One is to write an agent to traverse the view and write out each column.  That way you have complete control over all of it.  Another idea might be to create a web-accessible version of the view formatted how you would like.  You'd have to explicitly use the "count=" URL parameter to get all the documents though.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code linked below to use different delimiters:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

This would be the function to modify:

```
Public Function CSVArray() As Variant
    Dim rowarray() As String 
    Dim textrow As String
    Dim cnt As Long
    ReDim rowarray(rowcnt) As String

    ForAll r In row
        textrow = ""
        ForAll h In r.column 
            textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"\n") + |",|
        End ForAll
        rowarray(cnt) = Left$(textrow,Len(textrow)-1)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End ForAll  
    CSVArray = rowarray
End Function
```

Just replace the line

```
textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"\n") + |",|
```

with

```
textrow = textrow + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"\n") + |~|
```